# HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having a sytnax issue. I am trying to save an array of invoice items that belongTo Invoice. An invoice hasMany invoice items. The issue is that I am using this line to try to update the items but getting the error.

```
$update->invoiceitem()->save($item);
```

When creating as new items, it works. When updating I am not sure where my code is going wrong. I am using for to loop through the array. Here is the code:

```
$update = Invoice::find($id);
for($i = 0; $i < $count_ids; $i++){         
  $item = $update->invoiceitem; 
  dd($item); //this return the invoice items correctly. 
  $item->rate = $rate[$i];
  $item->total_hours = $hours[$i];
  $item->subtotal = $hours[$i] * $rate[$i]; 
  $item->type = $type[$i];
  $update->invoiceitem()->save($item);
}
```

The model relations are:

InvoiceItem Model

```
 public function invoice() {
      return $this->belongsTo(invoice::class);
    }
```

Invoice Model

```
public function invoiceitem() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceItem', 'invoice_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: your relationship is backwards, invoice has many invoice items and invoice items belong to one invoice. you don't need to specify the local and foreign keys either if they are setup through migrations properly

Comment: You don't need to save through the relation if the item exists. it would just be `$Item->save()` when updating.

Comment: @Bryan when I tried that earlier was getting Method save does not exist.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio see btl's comment about the relationships. Fix that first. I think you're trying to `save()` on a collection instead of a model with the relation the way it is.

Comment: Reading through this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Post would be equivalent to Invoice. And here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse Comments would be equivalent to my InvoiceItem. Not sure what  to fix if mine are backwards?

Answer (score 0):

The solution.

Find the individual invoiceitems by id that need to be updated and set them inside the for loop. As this is in an array the [$i] is important as without that it will only update the first record with the last array data.

```
$itemID= $request->itemID; //hidden in input. There are other ways of getting this value. 

for($i = 0; $i < $count_ids; $i++){         
 $item =  InvoiceItem::find($itemID[$i]);
  dd($item); //this return the invoice items correctly. 
  $item->rate = $rate[$i];
  $item->total_hours = $hours[$i];
  $item->subtotal = $hours[$i] * $rate[$i]; 
  $item->type = $type[$i];
 $item->save(); 
}
```